# 多言語サイトにおける機能提案とフィードバックについて

Tags: 討議, 他言語サイトでの提案

### 本文の前に

この投稿は、@NicolasChabanovsky さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された ["Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/341401) の和訳です。

Stack Exchange Network には、ここ日本語版スタック・オーバーフローをはじめ、英語以外の言語で運営されているサイトがいくつかあります。今回の投稿はそれらのサイトをどう改善していくかに関する提案です。

この提案へのご意見は[元の英語投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/341401)へ英語で投稿することもできますし、今ご覧のこのメタ投稿へ日本語で投稿することもできます。日本語のご意見は折を見て英訳し、元投稿の方に community wiki 回答として投稿したいと思っています ;)

お気軽にご投稿ください <(_ _)>

### 本文

Stack Overflow の最終的な目標は、コミュニティの助力のもと、プログラミングに関する全ての質問に対して詳しい回答がついた図書館を作ることです。それぞれ違う言語で運営される Stack Overflow サイトたちを過去何年かの間に立ち上げながら、素晴らしいユーザーの方々と共に、我々はびっくりするような冒険をしてきました。

[image]

今のところ、この旅は上手くいっています！　もし多言語サイトたちをひとつのまとまったサイトだと思うと、それは英語版 Stack Overflow の次にアクティブな、ネットワーク内で 2 位のコミュニティになるのです (1日辺りの質問数を基準としました)。しかし、多言語サイトとそれ以外の Stack Exchange Network を見渡してみると、ネットワーク上の多くのサイトにはあるのに多言語サイトだけにはない、とても重要なものがあると私は気づきました。今回はその「 **運営とコミュニティ間の双方向コミュニケーションの場** 」について書こうと思います。<sup>(訳注: ネットワークの運営企業を指す "the company" を「運営」と訳しています。)</sup>

#### コミュニティと運営は現在どうやってコミュニケーションしているの？

2018 年 1 月 1 日から 2018 年 6 月 15 日の間に、運営側の従業員は以下の通りの投稿をしました。

- Meta Stack Exchange: 282 件の回答。
- Meta Stack Overflow ロシア語版: 48 件の回答。
- Meta Stack Overflow スペイン語版: 28 件の回答。
- Meta Stack Overflow ポルトガル語版: 10 件の回答。
- Meta Stack Overflow 日本語版: 1 件の回答。
- Meta Stack Overflow 英語版: 412 件の回答。

もし運営の誰もあるコミュニティの言語を話せなければ、そのコミュニティはそれ以外のネットワークから孤立してしまうように私は思います。そういうことは起こって欲しくありません。私たちの成功の哲学は、コミュニティに大きく依存しているのです。皆さんのフィードバックによって、我々のサイトをインターネット上で Q&A をするための最高の場として徐々に作り上げていっているのです。コミュニティと対話しユーザーの方々の意見を聞く方法無しに、改善の見込みはありません。

#### どういう方法だったの？

最初の頃、それぞれの多言語サイトにひとり、バイリンガルな専任のコミュニティ・マネージャーがついていました。各コミュニティ・マネージャーによるコミュニティとの接し方はサイトによって異なりました。それぞれの多言語サイトにはそれぞれ異なる構想がありましたし、それぞれのサイトが焦点にしていることは互いに殆ど交わっていませんでした。こういった事情から、別々の多言語サイトに起きた似たような問題に対処するため、マネージャーたちが同じ仕事をすることも頻繁にあったのです。共に仕事をすれば、たくさんのエネルギーを節約できたでしょう。

#### コミュニケーションの改善

何か他の方法はないのでしょうか？　多言語サイト間で構想を共有し、他のコミュニティの経験を再利用し、全てのサイトからのフィードバックを元に行動できるようになれば、どうなるでしょう？　この目標のための最初の一歩は、運営とコミュニティ間、およびコミュニティとコミュニティ間において、アイディアや構想、フィードバックを交換するためのコミュニケーションの場を用意することです。

ここにおいて最も難しい問題は、運営も含め全てのコミュニティが異なる言語を使っていることです。これは誰が悪いのでもありません。現実です。このような状況があるため、どうやってコミュニケーションの場を上手く作るのかについて思い浮かんだ案を共有させて頂こうと思います。

## 多言語サイトにおける機能提案とフィードバックについて

> **TL;DR**
>
> - 運営・コミュニティ間およびコミュニティ同士の間でコミュニケーションをするための場が必要です。現在のところ、最も適切な場所は Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) です。
> - MSE における議論では英語を使い、多言語サイトにおける議論ではそれぞれローカルな言語をそのまま使います。
> - 運営側からの新機能提案は MSE に英語で共有されます。我々には、この提案をそれぞれのメタサイトへ翻訳して投稿するボランティアの方の助けが必要です。
> - コミュニティ側からの新機能提案はそれぞれ対応するメタサイトで共有され、MSE へ翻訳投稿される必要があります。その後、提案は上記のようにして全ての多言語サイトへ拡散できます。
> - 全てのメタサイトにおける議論は同期し続けます。
> - 多言語版のメタサイトにおける議論が大体終わったら、再度ボランティアの助けを借りて多言語版のコミュニティがどう思っているのかのまとめを作り、MSE へ回答として投稿する必要があります。

[image]

ここ数年にわたり、ロシア語版 SO ではたくさんの興味深い新機能を実装しようとしました ([例](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6))。たくさんのソーシャル活動も始めましたし ([例](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6))、エンジン部分についていくつか興味深い機能を組み込んで動かしました ([例](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6))。私は、これらの機能が他の多言語版コミュニティへは提案すらされていないことが気がかりです。他のサイトにおいてもシチュエーションは同じだろうと思っています。つまり、それぞれのサイトにはそれぞれのサイトのユーザー以外は知らないような提案があるということです。

これによって、多言語版コミュニティにとってとても重要な機能がエンジンへ実装されないことになるかもしれません。なぜなら、その提案は比較的少数のユーザーから必要とされているだけに見えるからです (それぞれ個別の多言語サイトで見た場合の話です)。それぞれの多言語サイトは個別にはそこまで大きくありませんが、先述したように、合わせて見るとネットワークで 2 番目にアクティブなコミュニティです。もし全てのコミュニティがその機能を欲しているのであれば、それに対して正しい優先度が付くであろうと思います。ただしこの最初のステップは、提案について共に議論し始めることです。

#### どうやって全ての多言語サイトに提案を伝播させるの？

複数サイトに渡ってコミュニケーションする方法について考える際、以下のことが前提条件です。

- この手順はスケーラブルである必要があります。もし多言語サイトが 100 個あったときを想像してみてください。サイトの数が何個であっても手順が簡単に行えるべきです。
- それぞれの提案を書く人は、必ずしも多言語サイトの全ての言語を使えるとは限りません。
- 提案はなるべく多くの人々が閲覧できるようにしたいです。これは、英語を使う種々のコミュニティのユーザーや、運営側の従業員も含みます。
- 提案について、多言語版コミュニティが彼らの言語で議論できる方法があるべきです。
- 多言語版のメタサイトにおける議論の結果はそれ以外のネットワークにも共有される必要があります。特に、他の多言語版サイトに共有すべきです。

これらのことを前提におくと、この手順がどのようになるかについて私はこのように思いました。

1. 提案の作者 (コミュニティ・モデレーターやユーザー) は MSE に特別なタグ付きで質問を投稿する (たとえば [[international]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) はどうでしょうか)。投稿は英語で為されるべきです。
2. 二つの言語を知っているユーザーはボランティアとなり、その質問を翻訳して、それを多言語版メタサイトへ投稿できます。
3. 多言語版メタサイトへ翻訳を投稿する際、MSE の質問へのリンクを貼ります。また、MSE の質問にも翻訳へのリンクを貼ってください。これによってメタ上の議論を同期し続けやすくなるはずです。
4. コミュニティによる議論の後、そのまとめを MSE の質問へ投稿するボランティアの方が必要です。このまとめは英語であるべきです。このとき、全ての多言語版メタサイトからのまとめを統合した、ひとつの wiki 回答があると良いのではないかと思います。こうすると、その回答を承認することでその回答を他の回答より上に置き続けられます。
5. 提案についてなにか意見のある方は、MSE を含めどのメタサイトでも回答できます。

コミュニティ側による提案の場合も、手順はほぼ同じです。ただひとつ違うことは、提案は多言語版メタサイトから始まり、MSE へ翻訳投稿される必要があるということです。その後からは全て同じです。

この手順を取ることで、運営側は全ての多言語版コミュニティが必要としていることを理解できます。同時に、多言語版コミュニティ同士でそれぞれ固有の問題についてアイディアを交換したり、提案を共有したり、多言語版 Stack Overflow でどんな素晴らしいことが起こっているのか知ったりすることもしやすくなるでしょう。

### あなたのご意見をお聞かせください！

我々は、多言語サイトをユーザーの第一言語を使ってプログラミングに関する質問をするための、インターネットで最良の場所にしたく思っています。最初のステップは、コミュニティがコミュニティ同士や運営とコミュニケーションする方法を作ることです。この目的に向けて、もしこの手順を改善するアイディアをお持ちでしたら、是非教えてください！

#### 多言語サイトでのメタ議論リンク

- ポルトガル語版: [Feedback e Iniciativas nos Sites Internacionais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7308/feedback-e-iniciativas-nos-sites-internacionais)
- スペイン語版: [Comentarios e iniciativas en sitios internacionales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3658/comentarios-e-iniciativas-en-sitios-internacionales)
- ロシア語版: [Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7847/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85)
- Русский Язык (Rus.SE): [Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/339)

#### タグ名についての追記

<sup>(訳注: 本家投稿において「タグ名は [international] じゃない方が良い」という投稿が[寄せられました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315461/341401)。)</sup>

- [internationalization と localization](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E5%8C%96%E3%81%A8%E5%9C%B0%E5%9F%9F%E5%8C%96) は良く知られた意味で広く使われている標準的な言葉なので、この提案のためのタグ名には不適切だと考えています。
- "Stack Overflow international" はあまり使われていない言葉です。今回の提案は多言語版サイトに関するものです。私の理解では多言語版サイトとはその UI が英語でないサイトのことで、現在では多言語版の各 Stack Overflow と [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) があります。
- タグ名は短い方が良いと私は思います。個人的には "international" (もしくは "international*s*") が良いと思っています。これは "stack-overflow-site" というのは使わないのと同じ理由です。

名前をどうするかについては未だに多くの疑問が寄せられています。もしタグ名をどうするかについて良いアイディアがあれば、是非お寄せください！

---

2018年10月1日追記: とりあえず今日までに日本語版へ投稿された意見は、翻訳・要約して元投稿に [community wiki として投稿しました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316185/341401)。

Answer (score 4):

#### 日本語版メタサイトにおけるタグについて

MSE から翻訳されて日本語版メタサイトにやってきた投稿に対してつける日本語版のタグが必要だと感じました。[他言語サイトでの提案](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%96%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e6%8f%90%e6%a1%88) でどうでしょう？

逆に、日本語版サイトから始まった提案の投稿に対しては、特に追加でつける必要は無いでしょう。

#### 翻訳の遅れにどう対処するかについて

この方法を行う中で最もイライラするのは、翻訳が遅れることでしょう。単にアイディアを外側へ広げていくだけならそこまで問題ありませんが、双方向に議論したい場合、翻訳の遅れは致命的です。

フィードバックを受け付ける締切を設けることである程度解消できるとは思いますが、翻訳ボランティアの方々をそれで急かすようなことはできるだけしたくありません。ボランティアが誰も時間をとれなかった場合、誰が翻訳することになるのでしょうか。

追記: 締切について元投稿で聞いてみたところ、Nic さんから次の[コメントを頂きました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/feedback-and-initiatives-on-international-sites?noredirect=1#comment1033461_315311)。

> Deadline is an interesting idea to look at. It seems to me that deadlines do not work well on metas, because users may answer any time in the future, even years after the implementation and suggest a better approach. It seems to be on case-by-case basis.
>   (翻訳) 締切は面白いアイディアだとは思います。ただ、メタにおいて締切はあまり上手くはたらかないのではないかと私は思います。なぜならユーザーは、たとえ実装から年数が経っていようと、未来のいつにでも改善案を投稿できるからです。採用するかはケースバイケースになるでしょう。

Comment: 単に「他サイト」という表現だと「StackOverflowネットワーク外」とも受け取れてしまう気がします。代わりの候補としては例えば「他言語サイトでの提案」とかでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick さん、ありがとうございます、反映しました。