# 各コミュニティが抱える問題や気づき、機能提案をまとめてみませんか？

Tags: 討議, 他言語サイトでの提案

この投稿は、@NicolasChabanovsky さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[Your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives)" の和訳です。

急いで訳しましたので、編集お願いいたしますm_ _m

---

**本文**

どのようにプログラミングを始めたのかを覚えていますか？おそらくみなさんが小さかった頃、放課後にグラフィックエディタを使ったり .imgと.exeファイルの違いを調べたりしたのではないでしょうか。そして、Turbo Pascalをインストールしたり面白い画像の代わりにダウンロードした「Hello World」に何かを追加しようと試みたことはなかったですか。そのレベルでの典型的なプログラミングアプローチは、「カウンターを増やす方法 - カウンターの行を何度かコピーする！」、そして関数やデバッガの発見は相対性理論並みに重要だったのではないでしょうか。

また、あなたが最も上達した時期のことを覚えていますか？それはもしかすると、あなたがプログラミング仲間に会った時に最も上達したのではないでしょうか。その仲間と一緒にいた最初の1ヶ月の間に、プログラミングを一人で勉強していた頃の12ヶ月間よりも知識が増えたのではないでしょうか。

私たちの多言語サイトでは成長するにつれてどうやら同じ状況が見られるようです。以下について考えてみましょう：

- すべての多言語コミュニティはサイトの標準的な構成から始まる。
- 各コミュニティは他言語コミュニティが直面する同様の問題にぶつかる。
- ある時点ではいくつかの問題が危機的になる。
- 多くの時間と労力を費やして危機的な問題の解決策を1つずつ探し出す。
- 他言語サイトで何が起こっているのかを知らないためこれらのソリューションから利益を得られない。
- ...同じ問題が他言語サイトでも危機的になるまで、苦しみ続ける。

お互いが協力し合うべきではないでしょうか？

**問題**

多言語サイトは何度も同じような問題に直面していますが、互いに孤立しているため、問題が他言語サイトで解決されたのかどうかを知らされていません。

**2つの例**

（1）サイト構成

ある時、ロシア語版スタックオーバーフローでは、挨拶付きの多くの質問を受けました。一部のユーザーが質問の編集を開始したため、レビューキューに多数の問題が発生しました。レビュアーは編集者に怒り、コミュニティは古い質問などを編集する必要がある場合これらの問題にどう対処するかについて議論を始めました。調査を開始したところ、質問が公開されたときに自動的に挨拶を取り除くように設定できるエンジンがサイト上にあることが判明しました。コメントの「ありがとう」と同じようなケースです。

（2）機能提案

Stack Exchange 社はユーザーインターフェイスを含むサイトを常に改良しています。時折それが原因で翻訳が失われます。翻訳状況を改善するために @g3rv4 が [traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/) を開発し、多言語コミュニティでは翻訳が失われることがなくなりました。残念ながら、traducir.win はすべてのコミュニティで使用されていないため、一部のコミュニティでは翻訳が失われ続けています。

**提案された解決策**

私たちが力を合わせて共に前進すれば、多言語コミュニティがさらに効果的になれると私は信じています。共同開発への第一歩は、すべての多言語コミュニティで、私たちの問題や発見、機能提案を分かち合うことなのです。

**このアプローチの本質**

「[多言語サイトにおける機能提案とフィードバックについて](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2748/%E5%A4%9A%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88%E3%81%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)」にあるように、各コミュニティの現在の問題と発見（いわゆる「解決済みの問題」）、機能提案についてのリストを保持すると良いのではないでしょうか。

例：[このような wiki回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives/317206#317206)。

この機能提案について何かアイデアがあれば共有してください。

同時に、あなたのコミュニティの現在の問題や発見、機能提案をリストに追加してください。フィードバックに基づいてプロセスを変更したとしても、リスト自体は実際の状況を確認するのに役立つからです。

Comment: アイデアそのものには賛成ですが、「機能提案」とは言ってもコミュニティに頼った「まとめ」であること、英語版の元投稿にも[コメント](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives/317206#comment1039487_317116)が付いていますが、他言語サイトで抱えている、または解決した問題へのリンク(自分のネイティブまたは英語以外で書かれた文章)を、果たして積極的に読んで理解する人がどれ位いるのかという疑問はあります。